# Fetching irregular data from CRM Dynamics

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm

I've created a fetch XML that gives me all the contacts in a marketing list. I also would like to get the name of the list baked into the output. I've found two ways to achieve that, none of which is satisfactory to the pedantic me.

1. Go to the DB and fetch the name as a separate request.
2. Have an extra column containing the name of the marketing list for each contact.

I'll be getting multiple (maybe even all) marketing lists from CRM so the second version seems most suitable as I'll make one call and get it all into a data structure that I'll play with (DataSet and such are fun). The problem is there that we're getting a lot of redundancy. How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to add the marketing list name into the fetch?

For example:

**Query:**

```
<fetch mapping="logical" count="50" version="1.0">
    <entity name="list">
        <attribute name="listname" />
        <link-entity name="listmember" from="listid" to="listid">
            <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="entityid">
                <attribute name="fullname" />
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

**Result:**

```
<resultset morerecords="0" paging-cookie="&lt;cookie page=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;listid last=&quot;{4EDF9ECA-A108-E211-801E-00155D505002}&quot; first=&quot;{4EDF9ECA-A108-E211-801E-00155D505002}&quot; /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;">
    <result>
        <listname>Test Marketing List Name</listname>
        <listid>{4EDF9ECA-A108-E211-801E-00155D505002}</listid>
        <entityid.fullname>James Maths Wood</entityid.fullname>
    </result>
    <result>
        <listname>Test Marketing List Name</listname>
        <listid>{4EDF9ECA-A108-E211-801E-00155D505002}</listid>
        <entityid.fullname>James Wood</entityid.fullname>
    </result>
    <result>
        <listname>Test Marketing List Name</listname>
        <listid>{4EDF9ECA-A108-E211-801E-00155D505002}</listid>
        <entityid.fullname>WoodJ Test</entityid.fullname>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

As a side have you seen the FetchXml builder included in the Stunnware Tools available from http://www.stunnware.com, its for Crm 4 but handles pretty much every 2011 fetch I've needed to create. Note: it didnt create the fetch for the marketing list above correctly, I had to change the link-entity to contact to contactid manually.

Comment: Yes, that's something like that I'm doing now. The problem with this approach is that one gets `<listname>Test Marketing List Name</listname>` at every `<result>`. I'd sleep better if I could have it on form `<foo><listname>Test</listname><result>...</result></foo>`. Is it achievable on server-side? I'd prefer to lower the bandwidth usage - for a large number of simultaneous clients connecting at the same time (e.g. at the start of a work day - 08:00 for **everybody**) that load might be significant.
`

Comment: I've heard about the builder for fetch XMLs but there's no such item on their web site, as far I could see...

Comment: In terms of the performance hit, I wouldnt worry about it until it became an issue, I wouldnt expect an extra field to make that much of a difference. In terms of stunnware, it looks like it just closed down, literally within the last hour they appear to have removed their links. It looks like it moved to here: http://www.donaubauer.com/en/#!StunnwareTools40&slide10

Comment: The question is answered, thanks. Now I've got another one [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635600/fetchxml-with-data-from-many-to-many-relations), a bit similar. Since I appreciate your answering style, I'd love if you had time to look at it too.